How can I use SQL commands UPDATE & INSERT INTO from an RShiny app?
I have created a SQL Server table in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) with 3 columns partNumber, numberOfBoxes & Quantity.
I also have a connection to that database using the RODBC Library in R. This is known to be working:
dbCon <- odbcConnect("SQL")
df <- sqlFetch(dbCon, "stockExample")

I am also trying to create an RShiny page that will allow the user to update the current stock levels or to add new stock levels - in SQL parlance, UPDATE or INSERT INTO.
My RShiny page is this:
page2 <- tabPanel(
  title = "Page 2",
 mainPanel(
   titlePanel("Adding Stock"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       helpText("This page allows the user to add stock.")
       ),
     mainPanel(
       "Add/remove stock based on partNumber.",
       
       textInput("ti1", "Part Number:"),
       textInput("ti2", "Number of Boxes:"),
       textInput("ti3", "Quantity:"),
       actionButton("action", "Submit")
     )
   )
 ) 
)

Such that the user enters the values for "ti1", "ti2" & "ti3". Clicking the actionButton will update the SQL table so that when it is reloaded on another page, or indeed in SQL, it will be updated.
I know my server function must take the input from "action" but I do not know how to proceed from there.
I have tried several options, 1 being:
output$action <- DBI::dbSendQuery(dbCon, "UPDATE stockExample SET numberOfBoxes = 5 WHERE partNumber = RD001")

This errors with:
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbSendQuery’ for signature ‘"RODBC"’
  50: stop
  49: <Anonymous>
  48: DBI::dbSendQuery
  47: server [C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Random\R Projects\'database'/app.R#81]
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbSendQuery’ for signature ‘"RODBC"’

There are others that I have attempted but to cut this short, I struggle to understand the syntax of them all. Is there a cheat sheet for RODBC, DBI or DBPLYR that gives the results I need?

Here is an example (using sqlite) showing how to create SQL INSERT statements based on shiny inputs:
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

stockExample <- data.frame(partNumber = character(0L), numberOfBoxes = integer(0L), Quantity  = integer(0L), 
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
if(!"stockExample" %in% dbListTables(con)){
  dbWriteTable(con, "stockExample", stockExample) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("ti1", "Part Number:"),
  numericInput("ti2", "Number of Boxes:", 0L),
  numericInput("ti3", "Quantity:", 0L),
  actionButton("action", "Submit", icon = icon("refresh")),
  tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  stockExample_rv <- reactiveVal(data.frame())
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    # also see DBI::dbAppendTable()
    sql <- sqlInterpolate(con,
                          "INSERT INTO stockExample (partNumber, numberOfBoxes, Quantity)
                           VALUES (?partNumber, ?numberOfBoxes , ?Quantity);", 
                          partNumber = input$ti1, numberOfBoxes = input$ti2, Quantity = input$ti3
    )
    DBI::dbExecute(con, sql)
    
    queryString <- sprintf("select partNumber, numberOfBoxes, Quantity from stockExample")
    stockExample_rv(dbGetQuery(con, queryString))
  })
  
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    stockExample_rv()
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server,
  onStart = function() {
    onStop(function() {
      dbDisconnect(con)
    })
  }
)


Please also check:
https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/best-practices/run-queries-safely/
https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/r-packages/pool/

The error says it:

Error in : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbSendQuery’ for signature ‘"RODBC"’

So you are trying to call a function DBI::dbSendQuery with an object dbCon of type RODBC for which there is no method defined.
The reason is that you are trying to mix 2 different frameworks for accessing the data, DBI and RODC. These 2 interfaces are not compatible and you should stick to either of them (here's a nice gist comparing the 2 approaches).
DBI::dbSendQuery requires a DBI connection object, while for a connection created with RODBC sqlSave is the function to save data to the backend (you may need to do the join in R and append only new rows with this approach, but I am a DBI user and not so  much familar with the RODBC interface).
TL;DR
Stick to one interface (DBI or RODBC) and use the framework specific functions but do not mix them.

With help from the 2 above, I found this works:
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
sql <- paste("INSERT INTO stockExample VALUES('",input$ti1,"','",input$ti2,"','",input$ti3,"');")
sqlQuery(dbCon, sql)
output$adjust1 <- renderText(paste(input$ti3, "of ", input$ti1, " have been added to location ", input$ti2))

})

Yes, this will work. However, it doesn't take into account any security mechanisms. Please read the article I linked.
